# how to get the value of the hidden fields in here after the radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to get the value of the hidden input fields on every click of a radio button. I have just posted a single div. I have a multiple div with same structure. I have successfully obtained the value of radio button but I want to get the value of hidden input now.

```
<div class="QA">
    <h1> First Question</h1>
    <input type="radio" id="check" name="q" value="A">Options 1</input>
    <input type="radio" id="check" name="q" value="B">Options 2</input>
    <input type="radio" id="check" name="q" value="C">Options 3</input>
    <input type="radio" id="check" name="q" value="D">Options 4</input>
    <input type="hidden" id="result" value="B" />
    <br/>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>       
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:radio").change(function() {
            checkResult(this);
        }); 
    });
    function checkResult(el)
    {   
        $this=$(el).parent("div.QA");
        $this.slideUp();       
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkResult(el)
{   
    $this = $(el).parents("div.QA");
    $this.slideUp();       
    var x = $this.find('#result').val(); //find value of hidden field in parent div
}
```

Change your markup

multiple `id`'s should not be used. Use `class` instead.

```
<input type="radio" id="check" name="q" value="A">Options 1</input>
```

to

```
<input type="radio" class="check" name="q" value="A">Options 1</input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try removing the hidden input entirely and indicate the correct answer using a data-* attribute. Something like:

```
<div class="QA" data-answer="B">
```

Then in your `checkResult` function you could retrieve this value using

```
function checkResult(el)
{   
    $this=$(el).parent("div.QA");
    var answer = $this.data("answer");
    $this.slideUp();
}
```

Comment: the problem is even in here when someone right clicks and see the source code the answer will be visible

Comment: If you want to stop people looking at the answer you'll need to keep it secret on the server and test each answer given with an AJAX call. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $hidden=$(el).siblings("input[type='hidden']");
```

BTW you have lot of elements with same ID, not good

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the hidden element by it's id.

```
var hiddenValue = $("#result").val();
```

You can use this in hidden function

```
function checkResult(el)
{
    var hiddenValue = $("#result").val();
    alert(hiddenValue);
}
```